# How to get response from an iron-form Polymer 1 request

Tags: javascript, polymer

i'm trying to get the response from an `iron-form in Polymer 1`.

Form submit call a php script which return HTML code to insert in a `div` (`ul` and some `li`).

I use the `iron-form` event "`iron-form-response`" but i don't know how to get the response.

I can see the response in network tab of browser developer tools, but don't know how to get it in my element.

I don't find how to do in the `iron-form` documentation [online](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form).

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Please post your code, and we'll be able to better help you. The demo for this element, which you can navigate to in your `bower_components` folder, shows setting up an event lister for `iron-form-submit`. Since it's listed in the docs, I imagine you could set up a lister for `iron-form-response` also.

Comment: According to the doc i use listeners and the iron-form-response event with a callback function. What i don't know is how to get the response in the callback function. I'll put my code as soon as possible. Thank you.

Comment: In fact what i want to do is to return from the form action an html portion ( ul and some li ), and insert this result in a div tag on my main page using iron-form, so AJAX.

I'm discovering Polymer elements and i'm testing some stuff. I agree the way i do is mayby not the good way !

Using the browser developper tools i see that event.detail is empty. So i try to return a JSON string. Here, event.detail return what i want. So i suppose this is the way Polymer, at least iron-form element, works, working with JSON.

Comment: To import html, you'll need to use Polymer's utility function `importHref`.

Answer (score 8):

What's happening, guys? All these responses confuse the OP when it is only this simple:

**Your form:**

```
<form is="iron-form" on-iron-form-response="responseHandler" action="http://localhost" id="myform">
   <!-- Your form elements -->
</form>
```

**Your script:**

```
<script>
   Polymer({
       // Some scripts here.

       // ...now your listener
       responseHandler: function(e) {
          console.log(e.detail.response);
       },                          
   });
</script>
```

It's just that. Nothing complicated. Don't over-complicate things.

Comment: how come this isn't in documentation?

Comment: There's a lot going on with Polymer development and a lot is changing now and then. Sadly, the documentations couldn't keep up with all the changes.

Comment: I think it is best to confirm if this is meant as a public api with the team. It may be removed in the future and that is why it is not in documentation. However, if not....that is a great find by you! Very cool.

Comment: For me this print in the console: `listener method `responseHandler` not defined` any idea on how to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Add Event Listeners to iron form.

```
ready: function(){
      this.$.myform.addEventListener('iron-form-response',this.formResponse);
      this.$.myform.addEventListener('iron-form-error',this.formError);
}
```

Form Response Function:

```
formResponse: function (e){
                    console.log("Server Response: ",e.detail);
}
```

Form Error Function:

```
formError: function (e){
                    console.log("Form Error: ",e.detail);
}
```

Comment: @Talon For me, e.detail only displays HTMLElement. There seems to be very little information available about where to actually PUT these listeners and functions, unless we're creating elements ourselves.

Comment: If you wish to access whatever content is returned, use event.detail.response. Be sure to (in the PHP page) wrap your response in json_encode(), though

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to build off of Talon's answer, which is correct.

`e.detail` will be a JSON object, assuming the response sent from the server is in JSON form. So, if you're using Node.JS and Express, you might have receiving code like this:

```
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('iron-form-response', function (e) {
    console.log('Form :', e.detail);
});
```

And your server code might look like this:

```
res.status(200).json({'foo': 'bar'});
```

After which `e.detail` will be the object `{"foo": "bar"}`

Comment: I've done as you recommend for error handling, but still get `error: Error: The request failed with status code: 500 at iron-request.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-request.html:231:32)
message: "The request failed with status code: 500"` instead of my custom json

Answer (score 0):

Small update.
I send some json with response:

`res.contentType('json');
es.status(500).send({"foo":"bar"});`

If I use 500 (error), I can reach the json data only by `console.log(e.detail.request.xhr.response);`
In case of code 200 it is reached by: `console.log(e.detail.response);`
Idon't get why it is so, but it's the only way for me((

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'rsvp-wedding',
      attached: function() {
        var form = document.querySelector('form');
        form.addEventListener('iron-form-error', function(e) {
          console.log(e.detail.request.status);
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
```